# blocking javascript/VBScript in URL

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I am developing a J2EE application. I have to avoid XSS attacks from my application. The most attack I have seen is "Sending javascript/VBScripts" over URL and getting all my info. Here is the sample URL,

http://application.com/application/main.do?var=10&job=alert(“Cookie”+document.cookie)

By using this above URL, attacker can easily get my cookie information.

So how to avoid these attacks by validating the above URL each time request submit to server ?

Regards,
Jerald.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the [OWASP-ESAPI](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/) project, but the basic principles are as follows

- never trust input from the user

  - lets say you need a number, then you would validate that number to ensure it is a number, otherwise reject it, this ensures that only numbers come through
  - if you need a title say, then you can already restrict to `[A-Za-z]{2,4}` for example.
- always encode output

  - anything that comes from the database/user should be encoded properly

Answer (score 0):

do not trust user input, and NEVER write it inside javascript tag. use `StringUtils.escapeJavaScript` and `StringUtils.escapeHtml` (from [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)) to sanitize.